# Soundcloud::ResponseError - HTTP status: 404 Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soundcloud

I am trying to get sound cloud user playlist to my ruby on rails website. But i face some problem with getting playlist of some user having playlist but showing Soundcloud::ResponseError - HTTP status: 404 Not Found.
For this user_id=209215443:

```
playlist = client.get('/playlists/209215443')
```

But when i use user_id:2050462

```
playlist = client.get('/playlists/2050462')
```

And show my expected result. Many user_id provide results and many user_id provide nothing. Why??

Comment: Accessing Sets for ruby code

# create a client object with access token
      client = Soundcloud.new(:access_token => '........')
# get playlist
    playlist = client.get('/playlists/209215443')
# list tracks in playlist
      playlist.tracks.each do |track|
        puts track.title
      end

Comment: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#accessing-sets